# Elastic search with Java: exclude matches with random leading characters in a letter

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am new to using elastic search. I managed to get things working somewhat close to what I intended. I am using the following configuration.

```
{
"analysis": {
"filter": {
  "shingle_filter": {
    "type": "shingle",
    "min_shingle_size": 2,
    "max_shingle_size": 3,
    "output_unigrams": true,
    "token_separator": ""
  },
  "autocomplete_filter": {
    "type": "edge_ngram",
    "min_gram": 1,
    "max_gram": 20
  }
},
"analyzer": {
  "shingle_search": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase"
    ]
  },
  "shingle_index": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "shingle_filter",
      "autocomplete_filter"
    ]
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I have this applied over multiple fields and doing a multi match query.

Following is the java code:

```
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                      .withQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(i)
                        .field("title")
                        .field("alias")
                        .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
                        .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.BEST_FIELDS))
                      .build();
```

The problem is it matches with fields that have letters with some leading characters.

For example, if my search input is "ron" I want it to match with "ron mathews", but I don't want it match with "iron". How can I make sure that I am matching with letters having no leading characters?

Update-1
Turning off fuzzy transposition seems to improve search results. But I think we can make it better.

Comment: Why don't you use regex ^ron

Comment: @user1001 Am I doing it right? Because, this does not seem to work.

String searchInput = "^"+i;
    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(searchInput)
          .field("title")
          .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
          .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.BEST_FIELDS))
        .build();

Comment: Try this \bron\b..  The one i mentioned is starts with.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to score "ron" higher than "ronaldo" and the exact match of complete field "ron" even higher so the best option here would be to use few [subfields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) with `standard` and `keyword` analyzers and boost those fields in your `multi_match` query.

Also, as you figured out yourself, be careful with the fuzziness. Might make sense to run 2 queries in a `should` with one being fuzzy and another boosted so that exact matches are ranked higher.